# AFNetworking 2.0 : error 503 when multipart POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.1.0 to communicate between my iPad app and my server.

I subclass AFHTTPSessionManager and use the following without problem :

```
[self POST:kAPIPath
parameters:params
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                  successBlock(responseObject[@"result"]);
              }
   failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                  failureBlock(error);
              }];
```

But when I add the multipart portion, my server returns

> request failure. error: Request failed: service indisponible (503)

So this does not work :

```
[self POST:kAPIPath
parameters:params
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:uploadFile
                                            name:@"file"
                                        fileName:@"photo.jpg"
                                        mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                }
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                  successBlock(responseObject[@"result"]);
              }
   failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                  failureBlock(error);
              }];
```

But it also returns error 503 when I just do this (nothing modifying the formData) :

```
[self POST:kAPIPath
parameters:params
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                }
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                  successBlock(responseObject[@"result"]);
              }
   failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                  failureBlock(error);
              }];
```

or this (nil for the block):

```
[self POST:kAPIPath
parameters:params
constructingBodyWithBlock:nil
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                  successBlock(responseObject[@"result"]);
              }
   failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                  failureBlock(error);
              }];
```

I read many posts, but can not understand where this can come from. The error 503 means

> 503 Service Unavailable
>   The server is currently unavailable (because it is overloaded or down for maintenance).[2] Generally, this is a temporary state. Sometimes, this can be permanent as well on test servers.

But if I use the POST without the multipart, I have no problem. Does anyone have an idea where this could come from ?

Thank you very much !!!

Comment: 5 hundred family errors shows rather a problem on the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I think it is the same problem as the one stated and commented [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031037/1668837). It seems to be a (recently) known issue in AFNetworking 2.0 with multipart form : [issue 1398](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1398). I used the workaround proposed by Matt at the bottom, and it's working.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You were correct, the way of using the multiform is the one below. I'd suggest you to check your server. Try using [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) to debug your multiform directly in your browser.

```
 [self POST:kAPIPath
parameters:params
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:uploadFile
                                            name:@"file"
                                        fileName:@"photo.jpg"
                                        mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                }
   success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
                  successBlock(responseObject[@"result"]);
              }
   failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
                  failureBlock(error);
              }];
```