# AFHTTPSessionManager post request

Tags: nsurlsessiondatatask, afhttpsessionmanager

I want to post a request to server. It is working fine if I am using NSURLSessionDataTask. But underneath I need to use AFNetworking as my whole application is using it. But when I am trying to hit the same service in AFHTTPSessionManager with POST method, It is giving me request time out.

Below are both the codes.

```
NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"BASE URL"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = @"1";

NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

AFNetworking kit version :-

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *client = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"BASE URL"]];

NSDictionary *request = @{@"Content-Type":@"application/json",
                          @"Accept":@"application/json",
                          };


NSString *postString = @"1";

NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


[client POST:@"" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:request body:data];
} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}];
```

Please help me in implementing it in right way.

Comment: please refer to the attached problem. In my case also body is Nil...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774692/afnetworking-multipart-request-body-is-nil

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating my own request and give its configuration to AFURLSessionManager and then holding my own NSURLSessionUploadTask object.

Thanks

Comment: It would be fantastic if you posted some of the solution.